# Table with post button

Tags: php, html

i get data from my mysql database and want to make a list.
in the list i want a button that uses post to send a value to the next page.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM all");
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo"<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Naam</th>
    <th>Eigenaar</th>
    <th>Plaats</th>
    <th>Bewerk</th>
    </tr>";
    ?>
    <form action="editshop.php" method="post">
    <?php
    while($rij = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

    ?> 


        <?php
        echo "<tr><td>".$rij['id'] . "</td><td> " . $rij['naam'] ."</td><td>";
        echo $rij['eigenaar'] . "</td><td>" . $rij['plaats']."</td>" ;
        echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=".$rij['id']."  /><td><input type=\"submit\" /></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</form></table>";
```

the table looks good but when i pres the button and the editshops.php opens wher i have `echo $_POST["id"];`
it always the last id of the list.
i only want the number thats the same as the id in the list.
in the list the id's are shown good.
What have i done wrong
(sorry if the layout of this post is not good this is my firstpost and i dont understand how to highlight the code)
**Update**
changed the loop to

```
<?php
    while($rij = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

    ?> 
        <form action="bewerkshop.php" method="post">

        <?php
        echo "<tr><td>".$rij['id'] . "</td><td> " . $rij['naam'] ."</td><td>";
        echo $rij['eigenaar'] . "</td><td>" . $rij['plaats']."</td>" ;
        echo"<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"id\" value=\"".$rij['id']."\"  /></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</form></table>";

?>
```

all working now but the names of the buttons are the id number can i change it to edit.
so all the buttons say edit and not the id number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I'm not sure if you want to edit multiple rows with a submit or only one. My answer is only helpful for editing multiple rows.

You're writing an input field for each row, all with the same name. That's the reason why the last one overwrites all the others.

You need to name your input field accordingly.

Example:

```
<input name="naam[1]" value="..." />
```

Where 1 here is the ID of your row.

You can then iterate over $_POST['naam'] and fetch the values.

```
foreach ($_POST['naam'] as $id => $value) {
    $otherValue = $_POST['otherValue'][$id];
    // ...

    // do something with it and add some checks if the keys exist.
}
```

Comment: i creata a list of shops. after the list i want a button were i can click on so i can edit the chosen shop

Comment: @SvenB I think that puts you back to using a form for each row or some javascript to identify the right row - or as wich suggests, drop the hidden field and attach the value to the submit button (Not tried that one personally)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I believe you need to use something like `name="id[]"` to get an array</strike>

I see now that you have a submit button per row, that means you need to make a form per row, or put the id value in the submit button itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `<input>` is missing a set of quotes around the value:

```
value=\"".$rij['id']."\"
```

Should do the trick properly.

Also however, if you are using the same name for each input, PHP will overwrite the data to the last ID sent (As all the hidden inputs have the same name).

You might want to consider making a form for each row of data. so you know which one was actually sent - or use some javascript to submit the form and select the right value to pass.

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. He's writing an input field for each row, all with the same name. That's the reason why the last one overwrites all the others.

Comment: Yes, I read the part you added afterwars in your edit :P However, a form for each row would affect the user experience negatively and a JS that puts everything together would be rather complex. // Edit: OK, I'm not sure if he wants to edit multiple rows with a single submit or not...

Comment: @DanielM Seeing as they are hidden fields, they will *all* be passed however, it isn't a selectable option. If the OP passes the entire set of IDs, then it is as useless to him as passing the last one only. He *needs* to either make a bunch of forms or use some javascript to identify the right one - or change hidden fields into a selectable form type.

Comment: Ahhh, okay, I saw the comment pop up after I made the edit. My bad (it was seconds after the original post)

Answer (score 0):

because all your hidden input have the same name when you post it will give you the last id either you can post as an array

```
"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id[]\" value=".$rij['id']."  />
```

or post them by passing the id to the submit button itself.